# How to find the average from reference schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I hope to find the average rating score of book reviews by book id/title.

Book schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bookSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  thumbnail: String,
  authors: [String],
  price: Number,
  edition: String,
  publisher: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Publisher'
  },
  _createdBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  bookReviews: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'BookReview'
  }]
}, { timestamps: true });

bookSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

mongoose.model('books', bookSchema);
```

BookReview schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const bookReviewSchema = new Schema({
  message: String,
  rating: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 5, default: 0 },
  _createdBy : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  _book: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Book' }
}, { timestamps: true });

mongoose.model('bookreviews', bookReviewSchema);
```

Sample documents for **Book**:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214"
    },
    "authors": [
        "L.L. Cheng",
        "Y.W. Faan"
    ],
    "bookReviews": [
        {
            "$oid": "5acce656e4b54b00142cae0c"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5acce65fe4b54b00142cae0e"
        },
        {
            "$oid": "5acedbbf56bd3c001467672e"
        }
    ],
    "title": "Aristo Exam Success Series",
    "thumbnail": "https://res.cloudinary.com/v1522940244/9789888361175_ao48tu.jpg",
    "_createdBy": {
        "$oid": "5ac61a414d19c30014232777"
    }
}
```

Sample document for **BookReview**:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5acce656e4b54b00142cae0c"
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "message": "excellent",
    "_book": {
        "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5acce65fe4b54b00142cae0e"
    },
    "rating": 4,
    "message": "good",
    "_book": {
        "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214"
    }
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5acedbbf56bd3c001467672e"
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "message": "ok",
    "_book": {
        "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215"
    }
}
```

There are two ratings (5 and 4) for book with id "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214" and one rating (5) for book with id "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215". I hope to find the average rating of the two books. Something looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "book": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214",
        "averageRating": 4.5
    },
    {
        "book": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215",
        "averageRating": 5
    }
]
```

I am new to Node.js and Mongoose and have no idea how to do this. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is as simple as:

```
db.BookReview.aggregate([
 {$group:{_id:"$_book", averageRating:{$avg:"$rating"}}}
])
```

And the output is:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215"),
"averageRating" : 5.0
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214"),
 "averageRating" : 4.5
}
```

Few things to point out in your data set:

```
"_book": {
    "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215"
}

"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214"
}
```

This is as simple as writing in the form:

`"_book" : ObjectId("5ac639554bc06e0014b4f215")` or

`"_id" : ObjectId("5ac639554bc06e0014b4f214")`

Now, how to do in node.js, pretty much simple since you already have the query. I will leave that job to you: [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805772/how-to-mongodb-aggregation-in-node-js)

Comment: Easy and nice solution, just tried in node.js and it works! thanks !