# How to rename fields in MongoDB output?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to `MongoDB`, my native language is Spanish. So I'm not sure how to find what I need.

I will try to make myself understandable.

I do this query and the result is an array.

**For example :**

```
Users.find({passport:123, (err, result) => {
   //output of result
   [ 
     {"nombre":"pedro","apellido":"jose"},
     {"nombre":"pablo","apellido":"jacinto"},
     {"nombre":"jose","apellido":"berta"},
   ]
```

I want to know if there is a more effective way to do something so that using some function from mongodb I can customize the output to avoid doing something like this:

**Required Output :**

```
   [ 
     {"name":"pedro","lastname":"jose"},
     {"name":"pablo","lastname":"jacinto"},
     {"name":"jose","lastname":"berta"},
   ]
```

is there any way to process the output information directly from mongoDB?

Comment: So do you wanted to `nombre` convert to `name` & `apellido` to `lastname` ? If yes there is no such thing that does directly,  but you can write query to map `nombre` to `name`..

Comment: result.map((element)=>{ return {name:element.nombre,lastname:element.apellido} } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MongoDB's [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to do that :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Filter docs based on criteria */
  {
    $match: {
      passport: 123
    }
  },
  /** Transform fields into required form */
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$nombre",
      lastname: "$apellido"
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z8c6jm8QXcy)

**Ref :** [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) , [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Comment: I am using mongoose, I am too new, in this .. how can I get the result? a callback does not work   Transaccion.aggregate([{...}], (err, value) => {})

Comment: @yavg : callbacks should work, are you seeing any error ? Check this in case if you think callbacks don't work :: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805772/how-to-mongodb-aggregation-in-node-js)

Comment: I am getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/UH13l1C.jpg , can you please tell me how to correct it. I do not understand and excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @yavg : As error says you should pass all stages in an array like :: `.aggregate([{},{}])` but not like :: `.aggregate({},{})`

Comment: @yavg : It seems ok, is that throwing an issue ?

Comment: @yavg : Not sure why, but it looks ok, you can check syntax in above SOF link, or post a new question with this code issue..

Comment: EXCUSEME, my error.  I don't know what I was doing wrong, but now it's working perfect. I have one last question before I rate you as the best answer. I am getting an error because I am trying to parse a date on a string that does not yet take its value. Is there a way to avoid having this problem without putting my `oFiltroMap` variable inside the `.aggretate`? https://i.imgur.com/qXGxHXd.jpg

Comment: @yavg : You cannot use a `.js` library in mongodb query, There are few aggregation operators that can help you to convert date to a particular format, Check this :: (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) Or please post a new question with date in DB & required format that you want..